# How to find PFUser with constraints?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I have tried to figure out how to find a PFUser with constraints, this is the only way I found. I don't know if I'm doing it wrong, but how would you display the results? When I try to display the results with println(query) it returns PFQuery surrounded by brackets (these <>) and it says PFQuery: and some random letters and numbers, I am most likely displaying it wrong that's why I'm wondering how to display it correctly. (Sorry I'm a newb)

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "username = 'Ethan'")
var query = PFQuery(className: "_User", predicate: predicate)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the whereKey method. And Parse also has a query specifically for the PFUser class.

```
    var query = PFUser.query()
    userQuery?.whereKey("username", equalTo: "Ethan")

    userQuery?.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock({ (result, error) -> Void in
        if let thisUser = result as? PFUser {

            println(thisUser.username)

        }

    })
```

Comment: YES!!! Thank you so much! Also one other thing would you know how to search for a user based on just one letter in their name? Like if I typed in "a", Andrew, Alex, Alfred, etc would come up.

Comment: No problem. To query for a specific string in a key you can use     userQuery?.whereKey("username", containsString: "a")

Comment: but remember, if you are querying for more than one result, you should use findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock() instead of getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock() — Also if you could accept my answer above by clicking the little √ button, it would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: I changed the code and I it says... if let thisUser = result as? PFUser and it says that cast from AnyObject to unrelated object PFUser always fails.

Comment: I just changed it to what you said for containsString but I fixed it so nevermind.